# Node js server is not visible externally

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, angular, client-server

I have a strange problem on my production server. When I run it using `pm2` I can access to data from this server using `http request to: 127.0.0.1:3003/get`

But it does not work when I want to do the same from my computer. Putting `10.83.2.70:3003/get` does not work. Angular shows connection refused. 
Do I have to change an address in Angular component from localhost to 10.83.2.70?

Regards